# How to show display data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new in react. Last day i tried to do work with Firebase in a react JS project. But i stuck on that. I set up sign in method according to the Firebase and i wanted to display all display name,email,photoUrl from the user who are sign in through sign in button.But i faced a problem i couldn't show these data but my console said i passed data successfully. I saw all data by console but why i don't show on the page. I try to fix all error but it's not change anything.My code is below:

```
import './App.css';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from './firebase.confige';
import React,{useState} from 'react';


// firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

if(!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
function App() {

const [user,setUser] = useState( 
{
isSignIn: false,
name: '',
email: '',
photo: ''
})

console.log(user)

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

const handleSignIn = ()=>{
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(res => {
 const {displayName, photoURL, email} = res.user;
  

  const signedInUser = {
    isSignIn:true,
    name: displayName,
    email: email,
    photo:photoURL
   }
  setUser(signedInUser);
  // console.log(displayName,email,photoURL);
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(err.message);
 })
}
return (
 <div className="App">
 <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</button>
 {
   user.isSignedIn && 
   <div>
     <p> Welcome, {user.name}</p>
     <p>Your email: {user.email}</p>
     <img src={user.photo} alt=""/>
   </div>

   }
   </div>
  );
 }

export default App;
```

firebase.Confige.js file is here:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyBPt45m9rGYcMJy5Ynq4PtEroNsSDYUcUM",
authDomain: "ema-john-simple-61839.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "ema-john-simple-61839",
storageBucket: "ema-john-simple-61839.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "813068797804",
appId: "1:813068797804:web:297c9d66d20a005cd15549",
measurementId: "G-8DGK2DEVBS"
};
export default firebaseConfig;
```

**first starting with sign in**
[image: starting with sign in method]
**console show user name email and photo**
[image]

**display show nothing**
[image]

**I didn't find out any solution please help me why this is happening i have to find out**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for value `user.isSignedIn` in your JSX and, if truthy, are displaying your values.

However, earlier in your `handleSignIn` method, you adjust the property `isSignIn` value to true if the sign-in is successful.

You should be checking for `isSignIn` in your JSX instead of `isSignedIn`.